# How to setup HLS Live Video Streaming from iOS Device

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, server, http-live-streaming

Good day everyone!

So, as the title suggests, i am developing an app with similar functionality to that off **Periscope and Facebook Live video streaming**. Here is what the end goal is:

- A Broadcasting device [user]
- EC2 Instance [Hosting an ffmpeg transcoder]
- Cloudfront Distrubution [CDN]
- 1 to n viewers of the live feed

I've been doing a lot of googling and what I **cant** seem to figure out is:

> As you send chunks of video to the server from the Broadcaster, how do 
>   you create an
>   .m3u8 playlist when you don't have all the chunks of video yet (e.g. the 
>   device sends its first 5second chunk of video)?

It seems a .m3u8 file is created from a .mp4 file that is already complete, then broken down into chunks... But i'm sending chunks of the video to the server, how can it generate the .m3u8 file when more chunks are still coming from the Broadcaster, so the watchers / clients can continuously stitch together the video chunks?

I'll be happy to clarify this question further. Thanks!

Comment: Does [this GitHub](https://gist.github.com/RLovelett/6791bde80575fc412983) link help?

Comment: @ProgrammingEnthusiast Thank you, but I had already seen that link. The procedure breaks down an already complete .mp4 file... But since this is going to be a LIVE stream, the mp4 files will be in 5second chunks. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the docs for the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment) you can specify the m3u8 to be outputted and you can also tell it to update the m3u8 as it goes. It might look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0 -f ssegment -segment_list playlist.m3u8 -segment_list_type hls -segment_list_size 10 -segment_list_flags +live -segment_time 4 outchunk%07d.ts
```

Note the segment_list_size is the maximum number of chunks referenced in the m3u8 file at one time and the segment_list_flags tells ffmpeg that this a live stream.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is that you are trying to send HLS fragments to their server. Don’t. Send a stream via another protocol like RTPM. Then let the server convert to HLS.